# Error: variable referenced before assignment

Tags: python, function

```
import random
import time
print ("Welcome to the Game")
print ("You must complete the next 10 Multiplication Questions to be truly ready for the challenges of life")
print ("")
choice = input("Are you ready? Y / N: ")
print("")

def play():

    while questions != 10:
        num1 = random.randrange(9,17)
        num2 = random.randrange(6,17)
        print("What does " + str(num1) + " x " + str(num2) + " = ")
        guess1 = input("Your guess?: ")
        answer1 = (num1*num2)
        if  int(guess1) == answer1:
            print("Correct")
            time.sleep(1)
            counter = counter + 1
            questions = questions + 1
            print("")
        else:
            print("Your answer was Wrong")
            time.sleep(1)
            print("The real answer was")
            time.sleep(1)
            print (str(answer1))
            questions = questions + 1
            print("")

        if questions == 10:
            print ("You got " + str(counter) + " out of 10")
        return
play()
```

Comment: please describe the problem in more detail. We are not telepaths and cant see which line or which variable your code is breaking at.

Comment: You should at least post the full error and describe what about it you're having trouble fixing.

Comment: I don't see you defining `questions` anywhere before trying to use it. That's the only place I can see that error happening

Comment: In general, where a question does not feature any body text at all, I vote to close. It should not be too much trouble to add a sentence or two of introduction.

Answer (score 0):

From the information available for now, I would say that this is because you did not assign any value for
    questions
variable

To solve this, simply add
    questions = 10 # or other value you may want
at the very start of the play() function

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize `questions` variable to `0` before `while` loop and also initialize `counters` variable to `0` and `return` statement should be outside while loop.

Below is the corrected code

```
import random
import time
print ("Welcome to the Game")
print ("You must complete the next 10 Multiplication Questions to be truly ready for the challenges of life")
print ("")
choice = input("Are you ready? Y / N: ")
print("")

def play():
    #initialization
    questions,counter =0,0
    while questions != 10:
        num1 = random.randrange(9,17)
        num2 = random.randrange(6,17)
        print("What does " + str(num1) + " x " + str(num2) + " = ")
        guess1 = input("Your guess?: ")
        answer1 = (num1*num2)
        if  int(guess1) == answer1:
            print("Correct")
            time.sleep(1)
            counter = counter + 1
            questions = questions + 1
            print("")
        else:
            print("Your answer was Wrong")
            time.sleep(1)
            print("The real answer was")
            time.sleep(1)
            print (str(answer1))
            questions = questions + 1
            print("")

        if questions == 10:
            print ("You got " + str(counter) + " out of 10")
    # return outside while loop
    return
play()
```

Answer (score 0):

An example for you:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6
import time
from random import randrange


def play():
    counter = 0
    for i in range(10):
        num1 = randrange(9, 17)
        num2 = randrange(6, 17)
        print(f"What does {num1} x {num2} = ")
        guess = input("Your guess?: ")
        answer = str(num1 * num2)
        if guess == answer:
            print("Correct\n")                
            counter += 1
        else:
            print("Your answer was Wrong")
            print(f"The real answer was {answer}\n")
        time.sleep(0.5)
    print("You got " + str(counter) + " out of 10")


def main():
    print(
        "Welcome to the Game\n"
        "You must complete the next 10 Multiplication Questions "
        "to be truly ready for the challenges of life\n"
    )
    choice = input("Are you ready? Y / N: ")
    if choice.upper() == "N":
        return
    print()
    play()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```